# java.lang.StackOverflowError when invoking action from Struts2 action tag

Tags: java, hibernate, plugins, struts2, stack-overflow

I have dccr.jsp file that calls an action via the  tag:

```
<s:action name="query-privilege" executeResult="false" var="privilege">
            <s:param name="moduleid">9</s:param>
            <s:param name="privilege">v</s:param>
            <s:param name="pagename">dccr</s:param>
</s:action>
```

i use this action to query module privileges amongst users, like this:

```
<s:if test="%{#privilege.allowable == false}">
       //do something
</s:if>
```

Here's my Action Support Class:

```
    private String pagename;
    private String moduleid;
    private boolean allowable;
    private String privilege;
    private final UsertypeModuleDAO umodDao = (UsertypeModuleDAO) ServletActionContext.getServletContext().getAttribute("usermoduleDAO");

    //loggers, session properties etc.

@Action(value = "/query-privilege", results = {
        @Result(name = "SUCCESSdccr", location = "/dccr.jsp"),
        @Result(name = "ERROR", location = "../error/messages.jsp")
    })
    @Override
    public String execute() {
        try {
            char p = privilege.charAt(0);
            int i = Integer.parseInt(moduleid);
            allowable = queryPrivilege(i, p);
            logger.info(privilege+", "+moduleid+", "+ut.getUsertypeid()+", "+allowable);
            return SUCCESS + pagename;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (emps != null) {
                logger.fatal("(" + emps.getIdnumber() + "):" + e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
            } else {
                logger.fatal(e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);

            }
            e.printStackTrace();
            addActionError(e.getLocalizedMessage());
            return ERROR;
        }
    }

    private boolean queryPrivilege(int moduleid, char privilege) {
        DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(UsertypeModule.class);
        criteria.createCriteria("usertypes", "ut").setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
        criteria.createCriteria("modules", "m").setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("m.moduleid", moduleid));
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("ut.usertypeid", ut.getUsertypeid()));
        UsertypeModule um = umodDao.getPrivilege(criteria);
        logger.info(um.getModulename());
        boolean p = false;
        switch (privilege) {
            case 'v': p = um.isViewable();
                break;
            case 'e': p = um.isEditable();
                break;
            case 'c': p = um.isCreateable();
                break;
            case 'd': p = um.isDeleteable();
                break;
        }
        return p;
    }

//getters and setters
```

And here's my code in my Data Access Object: 'umodDao':

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public UsertypeModule getPrivilege(DetachedCriteria dc){
        Criteria criteria = dc.getExecutableCriteria(session);
        criteria.setMaxResults(1);
        return (UsertypeModule) criteria.uniqueResult();
    }
```

When i run my project and navigate to dccr.jsp I get this error:

```
May 31, 2011 8:34:52 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.HashMap.get(HashMap.java:300)
    at java.lang.Package.getSystemPackage(Package.java:491)
    at java.lang.Package.getPackage(Package.java:313)
    at java.lang.Class.getPackage(Class.java:698)
    at com.googlecode.s2hibernate.struts2.plugin.interceptors.SessionTransactionInjectorInterceptor.isCandidadeClass(SessionTransactionInjectorInterceptor.java:313)
    at com.googlecode.s2hibernate.struts2.plugin.interceptors.SessionTransactionInjectorInterceptor.injectHibernateCoreSession(SessionTransactionInjectorInterceptor.java:340)
    at com.googlecode.s2hibernate.struts2.plugin.interceptors.SessionTransactionInjectorInterceptor.injectHibernateCoreSession(SessionTransactionInjectorInterceptor.java:361)
```

Yeah, Im using FHP(Full Hibernate Plugin 1.4GA) and my Servlet Container is Tomcat 7.0 on netbeans 7.0. I've been stuggling for days but kept failing at each attempt, The stacktraces point to FHP Plugin's SessionTransactionInjectorInterceptor.injectHibernateCoreSession method. Please help me or just say anything that may shed some light.

---

I have a suspicion that this problem had to do something with my tomcat policy, because when i upgraded to fhp 2.2GA I still came across with stackoverflowerror however

`java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method`)

is already included in the stacktrace. But this is only a suspicion. I cannot continue my work because of this problem so I am thinking of reverting my project's to the most recent working revision in order to continue my work and eventually commit my changes when I am able to fix this persistent problem.

Comment: Yup, the lastt line repeats infinitely...

Comment: It would seem then that the `SessionTransactionInjectorInterceptor` is the source of the problem. I'd take a look at what is going on in there.

Answer (score 1):

`java.lang.StackOverflowError` usually means a recursive call that has no stopping condition.  I'd start looking for one.

Comment: Thank you sir, however i dunno which specific part of my code does the infinite recursion.

Answer (score 0):

I've just checked the code of SessionTransactionInjectorInterceptor.

The use of `Class.getPackage()` partly causes the problem. They should not use `getPackage()` but parse the package name out of the class name.

I'm not sure how you can play around the issue. Loading a class from the same package *Before* running into the problem (i.e. somewhere in a static{} block) and calling getPackage() should help.

Overall struts2 should not use getPackage since it's intended for different purposes. (on top of that there are no performance benefits but needs to synchronize on a global lock).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem to yours, but somehow the problem magically fixed itself.  Whenever I ran it, I got this incredibly long couple of stack traces which were the result of a StackOverflowException.

I followed the advice of the first answerer and ran it in debug mode to see if there was some never-ending recursive call.  However, during debug mode the problem didn't present itself anymore.

My theory is that this stack overflow problem was somehow related to the Struts2 FilterDispatcher class.

If you can't find anything wrong with your code, that could be what's happening to you as well.  Especially, if your Struts2 project is more like a trial experiment for you with very little code and you know for a fact that you didn't use recursion anywhere in your code.